# If i develop c++ win32 GUI in xp ,will i have problem to run in it deferent win os's

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, porting

i need to develop win32 GUI in c++ (plain win32 windows.h thing ) , I'm developing it in xp os 
how much problem will i have to port it to vista and windows 7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a 'define' in Microsoft Visual Studio that allows you to indicate the minimum Windows platform that you want to support.  It's WINVER.

If you compile with WINVER=0x0501, then you are targetting Windows XP and above.
This means that you cannot call e.g. Windows 7 specific functions since they will only be defined if WINVER is set to 0x0700 or higher.

For the rest, check the Windows development documents that you will find on MSDN.  I noticed that in practice you won't have any problems unless you are doing special things with Windows Services or device-related things.

Answer (score 0):

No problems at all. the Win32 GUI api hasn't been deprecated

Other issues, like security, personal application files location, etc might give you a headache though.

Answer (score 0):

Check the article called ["Using the SDK Headers" or "Using the Windows Headers" in your Platform SDK/Windows SDK documentation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/20385891-df09-44b1-a40f-fb337b99cbc6/). There are many breaking change in Windows Vista and 7, so it is easier to upgrade to Windows Vistas if you make sure your programs runs under a normal user account in Windows XP.